# Is this Canon 70-200 F/2.8 IS II strap/sling attachment safe?

Tags: lens-mount, camera-straps

I received my 70-200 F/2.8 IS II today (YAY) and I knew it had a tripod ring, but I thought it also had camera strap attachment points on the tripod ring like some other heavy lenses do, but this one does not. I did not see anything in the manual about it so I thought I would ask here whether it is necessary to use the tripod ring to sling the camera or if my current setup (pictured below), which uses the camera body for one end and the tripod ring for the other, is adequate? It seems to me that even if the lens is heavy (my understanding is that this particular lens is more borderline-heavy) that this would put half of the weight on the lens, half on the camera body and the stress at the EF mount would not be much to worry about (but then I'm not an engineer or physics guru). Thoughts?

Edit: that's a 60d with a grip if it makes a difference.

[image]

Comment: This gives me the shudders. That is a very expensive body/lens combo. Its probably safe, the lens tripod mount is designed for both the body and lens. But it sure feels funny to me.

Comment: I only question it because the lens lacks strap attachment points such as is found in the 400mm F/2.8.

Comment: That's an awfully strange arrangement for the tripod collar on the lens, but I suppose it works. I've gotten a little wary of using a strap that hooks to the tripod socket, I've seen threads on various forums showing damage from it. It's really not designed to carry like that, in any camera brand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be, BUT: The question is, how secure is the screw.
I think with those "black rapid" straps, people had the screw loosen.

While in terms of forces it should be no problem at all, I personally would not be so sure about the screws staying "stuck" reliably.

Comment: It's for that reason that I don't use BlackRapid. I use the Cinch from LumaLabs which uses a traditional camera strap style attachment in conjunction with the Capture plates from Peak Design (which double as Arca and/or Manfrotto RC2 plates QR plates). In the picture I have a eye-bolt that I cut to length and the nut (not visible) helps keep it tight until my new Capture plate arrives. Those are very secure.

Comment: @tenmiles Provided that you trust the screws, that setup should not be causing any problems. Having said that though, I would recommend using the normal strap attachment - it gets used with heavier lenses as well.